# mikrotik не пускает пакет icmp ipv6

Tags: mikrotik, ipv6, icmp

mikrotik не пускает пакет `icmp ipv6`

сеть такая : клиент `alex` <-> `mikrotik` <-> `sql`. Везде запустил лог и получил такую картину :

```
alex
  fd00:a000::b62e:99ff:fe21:64f5

$ ping fd00:a000::56a0:50ff:fe7b:caee
PING fd00:a000::56a0:50ff:fe7b:caee(fd00:a000::56a0:50ff:fe7b:caee) 56 data bytes
^C
--- fd00:a000::56a0:50ff:fe7b:caee ping statistics ---
149 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 151555ms  
  
tcpdump :
  IP6 alex.sklad.rus > sql.sklad.rus: ICMP6, echo request, seq 1, length 64

---  

sql.sklad.rus
  fd00:a000::56a0:50ff:fe7b:caee

tcpdump :
  IP6 alex.sklad.rus > sql.sklad.rus: ICMP6, echo request, id 11, seq 34, length 64
  IP6 sql.sklad.rus > alex.sklad.rus: ICMP6, echo reply, id 11, seq 34, length 64

---

mikrotik
  fd00:a000::6e3b:6bff:fedb:5ada/64
  bridge2 pool = fd00:a000::/64

  invalid

  forward: in:bridge2 out:bridge2, src-mac 54:a0:50:7b:ca:ee,
    proto ICMP (type 129 (Echo Reply), code 0),
  fd00:a000::56a0:50ff:fe7b:caee->fd00:a000::b62e:99ff:fe21:64f5, len 64
```

Микротик этот пакет обозначил как **invalid** и не пропускает. Что не так с типом `ICMP 129` *(Echo Reply)* ? Как настроить связь этой сети `fd00:a000::/64` ?

А если пинговать глобальный адрес `2a03:e2c0:****`, то связь пашет и пинг тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему просто : настойчиво разрешил **invalid** пакеты

```
/ipv6 firewall address-list
add address=fd00:a000::/64 comment="local net" list=Local6

/ipv6 firewall filter
add action=accept chain=forward comment="Local net source NOT invalid" \
    src-address-list=Local6
add action=accept chain=forward comment="Local net destination NOT invalid" \
    dst-address-list=Local6
add action=drop chain=forward comment="Kill bad transit" connection-state=\
    invalid
```